# Very strange YouTube upload issue

Tags: youtube, upload

It's been a couple of weeks that I'm facing a very strange networking issue:

I am trying to upload a video to YouTube. Any video. I am using YouTube's web interface on the browser. Any browser (I tried all). From any OS (I tried win7, win10 and OS X). Using both wireless and wired internet connection.

Upon drag-and-dropping the video to YouTube's upload dialogue, the upload starts, the counter at the bottom-left corner goes all the way to 100% in the proper time frame (depending on the video file size) and I see the expected outgoing network traffic. All good.

However:

1. Save status (top right corner) reads "Saving..." for ever.
2. Process status (bottom left corner) reads "Upload complete ... Processing will begin shortly" for ever, after upload reaches 100%.
3. Video link doesn't get generated (when it should do so a couple of seconds after upload start).
4. Playlists list is empry, although a have a bunch on my account.
5. Thumbnails never populate.
6. I cannot save and publish the video, the "SAVE" button at the last step is greyed-out and the pop-up reads "Disabled while we prepare your video".

Looks like some background JavaScript or something process isn't working or doesn't communicate with whoever it was supposed to communicate with.

Strange thing is, that the described behavior ONLY happens when connected through my office network (I am the administrator of my network, I am a freelance engineer). Everything works as expected if I connect to some other network. Everything works absolutely fine when connected through a cellphone's hot spot, through the neighbors' WiFi, or even if I use a VPN! Nothing has changed on my local network for months. I have noticed NO other connectivity issues.

Any ideas? Where do I start? Only thing I haven't done is replace the main modem/router of my setup.

Comment: This question should perhaps be addressed to the administrator of your work network.

Comment: I happen to be the administrator of my work network.

Comment: Then has anything changed in the last weeks? Firewall? Security software? Hardware?

Comment: Nothing has changed. That's why I'm so puzzled by the issue. I've tried different computers, running different OSes and browsers, and the behavior is the same. As soon as I connect to a different network, everything works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

and...
just as this issue emerged, it has now completely fixed itself, with no particularly radical change from my side!

I always get frustrated when something that used to work suddenly doesn't, and then it works again for no particular reason...

I did contact the YouTube team through their feedback loop, maybe they did tinker their script, I wouldn't know, since I did not receive any correspondence. I will update this answer if I receive anything relevant during the next few days.

Comment: I wonder if this was some caching issue on your browser's end..

Comment: no way it could be the browser, since I tried 9 different browsers on three different computers.